# Add total rows to data frame by group using two grouping variables

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have the data frame like the one below with two grouping variables "Group" and "Gender" and two additional variables with counts:

```
Group <- c("Group1","Group1","Group2","Group2")
Gender <- c("Male","Female","Male","Female")
Y <- c(7,5,6,10)
N <- c(45,8,2,11)
data <- cbind.data.frame(Group,Gender,Y,N)

> data
   Group Gender  Y  N
1 Group1   Male  7 45
2 Group1 Female  5  8
3 Group2   Male  6  2
4 Group2 Female 10 11
```

I need to add a total number by group and gender while keeping the group name. Here's the output I am aiming for:

```
   Group Gender  Y  N
1 Group1   Male  7 45
2 Group1 Female  5  8
3 Group1  Total 12 53
4 Group2   Male  6  2
5 Group2 Female 10 11
6 Group2  Total 16 13
```

Could anyone suggest the best way to do this?

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `group_modify` for this.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  group_modify(~bind_rows(.x, tibble(Gender = "Total", Y = sum(.x$Y), N = sum(.x$N))))

# A tibble: 6 × 4
# Groups:   Group [2]
  Group  Gender     Y     N
  <chr>  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 Group1 Male       7    45
2 Group1 Female     5     8
3 Group1 Total     12    53
4 Group2 Male       6     2
5 Group2 Female    10    11
6 Group2 Total     16    13
```

Answer (score 2):

With `janitor::adorn_totals`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)
data %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  group_modify(~ .x %>% adorn_totals())

  Group  Gender     Y     N
  <chr>  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 Group1 Male       7    45
2 Group1 Female     5     8
3 Group1 Total     12    53
4 Group2 Male       6     2
5 Group2 Female    10    11
6 Group2 Total     16    13
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple 'dplyr' only solution:

I usually use one trick *before* using `count()` or any other aggregation: recode the group of interest into `"Total"` and then `bind_rows()` with the original data.

Below shown with the `iris` data set, since we only have your aggregated data.

```r
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
  mutate(Species = "Total") %>% 
  bind_rows(iris) %>% 
  count(Species)

#>      Species   n
#> 1      Total 150
#> 2     setosa  50
#> 3 versicolor  50
#> 4  virginica  50
```

Below I apply this to your original data as far this is possible without the unaggregated data. Missing here is the third variable which creates `Y` and `N`, we would need to include that into `count()` and then `pivot_wider()`, but probably this step is already part of your aggregation.

```r
data %>% 
  mutate(Gender = "Total") %>% 
  bind_rows(data) %>% 
  count(Group, Gender)
```

If you only have aggregated data, we can also use this approach but it gets a little bit more cumbersome, since we have to `summarise` again:

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  mutate(Gender = "Total") %>% 
  bind_rows(data) %>% 
  summarise(across(c(Y:N), sum), .by = c(Group, Gender)) %>% 
  arrange(Group, Gender == "Total")

#>    Group Gender  Y  N
#> 1 Group1   Male  7 45
#> 2 Group1 Female  5  8
#> 3 Group1  Total 12 53
#> 4 Group2   Male  6  2
#> 5 Group2 Female 10 11
#> 6 Group2  Total 16 13
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>